# UISlider - For Volume 0.0 to 1.0 - iOS XCODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, uislider

I have a UISlider that I want to use to manage the volume levels using AVAudioPlayer

The problem I have found that with the value set between 0 and 1. It only records either 0 or 1.

However, i want it to be able to confim the variables inbetween such as 0.1,0.2,0.3 etc up to 1.0 so I can use this value for adjusting the game sounds.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

I currently have...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
[slider setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sliderValue"]];

(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)slidetheslider {
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:[slider value] forKey:@"sliderValue"];
    GameSounds = slider.value;
    NSLog (@"Volume Level %d", GameSounds);
```

on the next VC, I reload the value saved....

```
GameVolume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sliderValue"];
NSLog (@"Volume Slider %d", GameVolume);
```

Thereafter I use GameVolume as the reference for the volume.

The problem is If I try 0.0 to 1.0 it only gives me a 0 or 1.

If I try 0 - 100 and then change GameVolume to this...

`GameVolume = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sliderValue"]/100;
    NSLog (@"Volume Slider %d", GameVolume);`

It still only gives me a 0 or a 1

Comment: You're converting the value to integer type. It's originally a CGFloat.

Comment: let the `GameVolume` be `CGFloat` instead of `NSInteger`. it can help you a lot.

Comment: how do I do that? Sorry but im still relatively new to this.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Set the minimumValue and maximumValue properties.  They default to 0.0 and 1.0, but are floats, and can be set to whatever you prefer.

Here's the docs:  [Apple Docs for UISlider](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

If you are reading values of only 0 and 1 you may be using improper types.  Please post relevant code.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0;
    [slider setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"sliderValue"]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)slidetheslider {
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:[slider value] forKey:@"sliderValue"];
    GameSounds = slider.value;
    NSLog (@"Volume Level %d", GameSounds);
       
}

Answer (score 0):

There is an mathematical option that you can use.Set the maximum and minimum to 0 to 100 and when you need a value divide current slider value by 100

minimumvalue :0
maximum value:100

```
-(float)getValueOfSlider:(CGFloat)sliderValue
{
    return sliderValue/100;
}

-(float)setSliderValue:(float)inputValue
{
    return inputValue*100;
}
```

Comment: No need. Simply go from 0.0 to 1.0. They're floats.